# Changing WSO2 Governance Registry (greg) List view

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Sorry in advance to mods who probably have already answered this question, but i cant seem to find any documentation on how to change specifically this distribution of WSO2's interface, my end goal is to change the following UI into a list without the square icons.

[Related Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z0YK.png)

i've found this https://wso2docs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/Governance540/pages/1048675/Custom+UI+Sample but the samples dont seem to be available

My particular version of WSO2greg is 5.4.0 and im ashamed to say it's been hard for me to find relevant documentation particular to this version of the software, i've found manuals and documentation for the default version of WSO2 API Publisher but not this one, can anyone help me out with this?

I've tried to follow the steps of manuals and tutorials related to api manager, but have had no luck yet, just want to list the apis as a list without thumbnails and add some more info to the preview.